# Change jdownloader icon of the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, jdownloader

This is what I see in the launcher when I open JDownloader

[image]

I don't want to create a launcher that always stay in the dashboard, I only want see the apropiated icon when open JD.

Comment: I don't know if it works for you, but I've installed jDownloader with [this ppa](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-jdownloader-in-ubuntu-10-1010-049-10-using-ubuntu-ppa.html) and it has the correct icon. Perhaps try reinstalling it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you report a bug, because this is a common problem with applications that use wrappers to launch.

JDownloader is a java application and uses a wrapper script, so it's going to be difficult to fix this issue, unless Unity is modified so it can track this better.

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and write this:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/jdownloader.desktop
```

add this line at the end of the file:

```
StartupWMClass=jd-Main
```

save it, and launch JDownloader

Comment: I had to do it trough gedit, because when I want to save the file with nano, tells me if doesn't exists. But it didn't work.

Off topic: why formatting code doesn't work?